# MCU C++ programm with endless-loop without side-effects allways UB?

Tags: c++, loops, interrupt, undefined-behavior, mcu

The following code

```
int main() {
    while(true);
}
```

is UB in C++. But this is a common practice in MCU programming: there exists an endless-loop in `main()` and all the work is done in ISRs (interrupt-service-routines).

The question is if in

```
void ISR() {
    // side-effects
}

int main() {
    while(true);
}
```

the endless-loop could be removed due to UB. In most MCU this leads to restart of the MCU.

Or is this simply non-conformat C++ code, since it contains an ISR: C++-Standard does not mention ISR, it only mentions signal-handlers installer via `signal()`.

Comment: Yes, it's formally UB.  A suitable fix might be: `volatile int i;` at global scope and then `while (true) i = 42;` in `main`.

Comment: Embedded environment have different requirements. Such cases are normally handled by compiler switches(tweaked in project settings). In cross IDEs, The default settings are the embedded preferences; standard settings should be explicitly and manually selected. On the other hand, return from entry point(`main` function) is eventually a side-effect; Therefore  IMHO infinate loops should not be considered UB.

Comment: Some MCUs have halt/sleep instruction. Using it not only eliminates UB but also reduces idle power consumption.